# How to fix the Grub2 Menu to have a correct Dual Boot Windows-Linux?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, linux-mint, grub2, repair

I have Windows 10 and I previously had installed Zorin distro and worked fine. Then I deleted from Disk Management in Windows the previous partition where Zorin (Ubuntu-like distro) was installed and I installed Linux Mint 19.

The issue is that now when I reboot the Grub menu for Dual Boot is not present, instead appears the message

```
               GNU GRUB version 2.02

Minimal BASH-like editing is supported...
...
...

grub> _
```

I've followed some step by step guides trying to fix the MBR or Grub but didn't work.

I've already tried to fix the grub using a live USB of Linux Mint and running the commands below

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda7 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt

grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

The I tried fix the MBR from a Windows 10 installation DVD running these 2 commands but that didn't work either, even when the commands where executed successfully.

```
bootrec.exe /fixboot
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

I can login into Windows10 only going to boot options and selecting "Windows Boot Manager" but when I let the normal booting without pressing F12 the `Minimal BASH-like editing is supported...` window appears.

What I need to do in order to set a working dual boot menu? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the Windows boot so far following this steps from [this site](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/124175-c-boot-missing.html). I hope help someone in the future.

```
Run command prompt from Windows installation DVD
diskpart
sel dis 0
sel par 1
del par override
cre par EFI
for fs=FAT32 quick
assign letter=T
exit
bcdboot C:\Windows /s T: /f ALL
exit

Then reboot the computer
```